# Get labels out of Python Gaussian Mixture Model clustering after PCA

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, cluster-analysis

I have a deep learning model which extracts features of the original time series data, then uses PCA to reduce the dimensionality to 2D, then perform clustering using GMM. I am then planning to use my clustered info to label a class of signals that I am interested in looking for in the original data. However, I'm having trouble wrapping my head around on how to do that since from my understanding, I have lost information after doing PCA. So is this possible, and if yes how would I go about it?

I first start with 3 columns of data, each with length 1780800. They are then reshaped to an array of size (108, 3, 16800) to be fed into the model.

The model I am referring to is as below:

[image]

Full research paper is https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-020-17841-x.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem right if you are using PCA on time points as feature values. What you need is a feature extractor that first converts the time series to euclidean feature space (Check feature extraction for time series).  Then, you can use basic clustering tools in sklearn and visualize it using TSNE to check if it makes sense or not. You need to validate each step before going into the next one.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't being clear enough, the model uses deep scattering network to extract features, then project to a 2D space, and then cluster the projected scattering coefficients. But I'm trying to understand how I would label the original data based on the clusters I have.